# Join every other line in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to combine every other line from the input below. Here is the input.

```
ALPHA-FETOPROTEIN      ROUTINE    CH 0203 001   02/03/2023@10:45 LIVERF3
     ###-##-####    #######,####        In lab
ALPHA-FETOPROTEIN      ROUTINE    CH 0203 234   02/03/2023@11:05 LIVER
     ###-##-####    ########,########   In lab
ANION GAP              STAT       CH 0203 124   02/03/2023@11:06 DAY
     ###-##-####    ######,##### ####   In lab
BASIC METABOLIC PANE   ROUTINE    CH 0203 001   02/03/2023@10:45 LIVERF3
     ###-##-####    #######,#### ###### In lab
```

This is the desired output

```
ALPHA-FETOPROTEIN      ROUTINE    CH 0203 001   02/03/2023@10:45 LIVERF3 ###-##-####    #######,####        In lab
ALPHA-FETOPROTEIN      ROUTINE    CH 0203 234   02/03/2023@11:05 LIVER ###-##-####    ########,########   In lab
ANION GAP              STAT       CH 0203 124   02/03/2023@11:06 DAY ###-##-####    ######,##### ####   In lab
BASIC METABOLIC PANE   ROUTINE    CH 0203 001   02/03/2023@10:45 LIVERF3 ###-##-####    #######,#### ###### In lab
```

The code that I have tried is

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $splitLines.Count; $i += 2){
  $splitLines[$i,($i+1)] -join ' '
}
```

It came from [Joining every two lines in Powershell output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528026/joining-every-two-lines-in-powershell-output). But I can't seem to get it to work for me. I'm not well versed with powershell, but i'm at the mercy of what's available at work.

Edit: Here is the entire code that I am using as requested.

```
# SET VARIABLES
$inputfile = "C:\Users\Will\Desktop\testfile.txt"
$outputfile = "C:\Users\Will\Desktop\testfileformatted.txt"
$new_output = "C:\Users\Will\Desktop\new_formatted.txt"

# REMOVE EXTRA CHARACTERS
$remove_beginning_capture = "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
$remove_end_capture = "==============================================================================="
$remove_line = "------"
$remove_strings_with_spaces = "            \d"
Get-Content $inputfile | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $remove_beginning_capture} | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $remove_end_capture} | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $remove_line} | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $remove_strings_with_spaces}  | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | Set-Content $outputfile

# Measures line length for loop
$file_lines = gc $outputfile | Measure-Object

#Remove Whitespace
# $whitespace_removed = (Get-Content $outputfile -Raw) -replace '\s+', ' '| Set-Content -Path C:\Users\Will\Desktop\new_formatted.csv

# Combine every other line
$lines = Get-Content $outputfile -Raw
$newcontent = $lines.Replace("`n","")
Write-Host "Content: $newcontent"
$newcontent | Set-Content $new_output

for($i = 0; $i -lt $splitLines.Count; $i += 2){
  $splitLines[$i,($i+1)] -join ' '
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, elaborate meaning of your statement  *I can't seem to get it to work for me*.

Comment: The code you are showing here is working as expected. It is the code you are not showing, that is the root of the problem. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read two lines and then print one

```
$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.txt"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.txt"

$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($inputFilename)
$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($outputFilename)
while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
{
   $secondLine = ""
   if(!$reader.EndOfStream){ $secondLine = $reader.ReadLine() }

   $writer.WriteLine($line + $secondLine)
}
$reader.Close()
$writer.Flush()
$writer.Close()
```

Comment: You're doing the PowerShell community a disservice if you keep posting solutions that treat PowerShell like nothing but a dialect of C#. While such solutions _technically_ work (a testament to PowerShell's versatility), you'll miss out on what makes PowerShell PowerShell: its many high-level abstractions, which make for more concise solutions. As an aside: you don't need to `.Flush()` a writer just before calling `.Close()`.

Comment: @mklement0 : Which is more efficient?  You again are wrong.  I've seen lots of cases where flush is needed, especially when the output is small.  Also PS doesn't always close the file unless you close the PS window.

Comment: @mklement0 PowerShell supports it, it is not a dialect but proper PowerShell. PowerShell itself is built on top of the .NET CLR. It is like saying that using WinAPI in C# is wrong and should not be done. A statement that provides nothing to any answer.

Comment: @mklement0 : My solution is much cleaner, less math, and more efficient.  To do module arithmetic is ridiculous in this case.  You are simply trying to do something the wrong way so you can say it can be done in PS, when it shouldn't.  PS does not have a method to read one line at a time.

Comment: The question isn't about performance, and while you can _fall back to_ direct use of .NET APIs (again, a testament to PowerShell's versatility) _if and when PowerShell's performance falls short_ in a given use case, this fallback - typically resulting in more code, and  notably requiring familiarity with a different knowledge domain - shouldn't be the _default_ approach, which it is in your answers.

Comment: This is leaving aside that there often PowerShell-native ways to improve performance too - in fact, if you use `Set-Content out.txt -Value $(...)` around the `switch` solution, it'll outperform your solution - try the benchmarks at https://gist.github.com/mklement0/e8cabb620342af37ae7d0faecba7d588#file-bm_75347681-ps1

Comment: Finally, to address your various incorrect claims: (a) As for flushing - see https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs,ab19992c30648b1d for proof that `.Close()` _automatically_ flushes.
If it didn't, it would amount to a serious design flaw. (b) `Get-Content` and `switch -File` (as shown in my answer) are two examples of PowerShell-native ways to read files line by line (though you can't directly read from _multiple_ files line by line in a loop/pipeline without help from either a steppable pipeline or .NET APIs).

Comment: What the "dialect" metaphor was meant to say: you're using PowerShell _as if it were C#_, which is ill-advised.

Comment: Code looks good to me, tho I agree with mklement0 you dont need to call `.Flush()` in this case. You could also just call `.Dispose()` with a loop `$reader, $writer | % Dispose` only time `.Flush()` was needed in my experience is when desling with MemoryStreams and in some very specific circumstances

Comment: @mklement0 : Where does it every say that c# is "ill-advised" in PS?

Comment: Nowhere. I  didn't say it, and neither would I ever say it. What I _did_ say (and meant to say) is: if you treat language X as if it were language Y, you'll end up writing un-idiomatic code that misses out on what makes language X worthwhile. In the case of PowerShell vs. C# / direct use of .NET APIs this means writing usually much more verbose code, while also potentially inducing newcomers to do so. This particular answer may not be the most obvious example, but it is part of a larger pattern; [this previous answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74395522/45375) is a better example.

Comment: @mklement0 " Read you own words : "What the "dialect" metaphor was meant to say: you're using PowerShell as if it were C#, which is ill-advised."  You can't do everything in PS format that you can in c#.  Somethings in PS you must use c# format like DllImport.  It is best to "Keep It Simple".  If c# make its simpler than use c#.

Comment: In addition to all of the above I just want to mention that stuff like Get-Content, Set-Content, etc. is literally pure c# under the hood and stating that some trickery with set-content and switch is still just pure c# which in itself calls loads of Winapi c++ parts. After more comments I do understand @mklement0 statements and where they are coming from though I don't agree with all of them.

Comment: @Max, PowerShell is built on _.NET_, not C# (that C# happens to be the language in which PowerShell itself is implemented is incidental). PowerShell provides its own language and commands (cmdlets), which operate on a higher level of abstraction than C# and .NET APIs; not using them means missing out on what the language has to offer. Direct use of .NET APIs is needed in two cases: (a) if no native PowerShell cmdlet is available for a given task or (b) to improve performance _if actually needed_. Direct use of .NET APIs always requires _additional knowledge_ and is usually more verbose.

Comment: @Max, as previously noted, this particular answer isn't the best example of "C# in PowerShell clothing", but it is a part of a larger pattern; to add another more obvious example to the previously mentioned one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75347998/45375. My answer now shows a PowerShell-idiomatic solution that is conceptually much simpler; the `-replace`-based solution even significantly outperforms this answer, but PowerShell isn't about performance, and optimization should only be attempted _if actually needed_.

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell-idiomatic solutions**:

Use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) with `-ReadCount 2` in order to read the lines from your file *in pairs*, which allows you to process each pair in a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call, where the constituent lines can be joined to form a single output line.

```bash
Get-Content -ReadCount 2 yourFile.txt | 
  ForEach-Object { $_[0] + ' ' +  $_[1].TrimStart() }
```

The above directly outputs the resulting lines (as the `for` command in your question does), causing them to print to the display by default.

Pipe to [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) to save the output to a file:

```bash
Get-Content -ReadCount 2 yourFile.txt | 
  ForEach-Object { $_[0] + ' ' +  $_[1].TrimStart() } |
  Set-Content yourOutputFile.txt
```

**Performance notes**:

- Unfortunately (as of PowerShell 7.3.2), `Get-Content` is quite slow by default - see [GitHub issue #7537](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7537), and the performance of `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` could be improved too - see [GitHub issue #10982](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10982).
- At the expense of collecting all inputs and outputs in memory first, you can noticeably improve the performance with the following variation, which avoids the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet* in favor of the [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach), and, instead of *piping* to `Set-Content`, passes all output lines via the `-Value` *parameter*:

  ```bash
  Set-Content $tempOutFile -Value (
    (Get-Content -ReadCount 2 $tempInFile).ForEach({ $_[0] + ' ' + $_[1].TrimStart() })
  )
  ```
- Read on for even faster alternatives, but **remember that optimizations are only worth undertaking *if actually needed*** - if the first PowerShell-idiomatic solution above is fast enough *in practice*, it is worth using for its conceptual elegance and concision.

  - See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/e8cabb620342af37ae7d0faecba7d588#file-bm_75347681-ps1) for **benchmarks** that compare the relative performance of the solutions in this answer as well as that of the solution from [jdweng's .NET API-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75348106/45375).

---

An **better-performing alternative** is to use a **[`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with the `-File` parameter** to process files *line by line*:

```bash
$i = 1
switch -File yourFile.txt {
  default {
    if ($i++ % 2) { $firstLineInPair = $_ }
    else          { $firstLineInPair + ' ' + $_.TrimStart() } 
  }
}
```

<sup>Helper index variable `$i` and the modulo operation (`%`) are simply used to identify which line is the start of a (new) pair, and which one is its second half.</sup>

- The `switch` statement is itself streaming, but it cannot be used as-is as pipeline input. By enclosing it in `& { ... }`, it can, but that forfeits some of the performance benefits, making it only marginally faster than the optimized `Get-Content -ReadCount 2` solution:

  ```bash
  & {
    $i = 1
    switch -File yourFile.txt {
      default {
        if ($i++ % 2) { $firstLineInPair = $_ }
        else          { $firstLineInPair + ' ' + $_.TrimStart() } 
      }
    } 
  } | Set-Content yourOutputFile.txt
  ```
- For the best performance when writing to a file, use `Set-Content $outFile -Value $(...)`, albeit at the expense of collecting all output lines in memory first:

  ```bash
  Set-Content yourOutputFile.txt -Value $(
    $i = 1
    switch -File yourFile.txt {
      default {
        if ($i++ % 2) { $firstLineInPair = $_ }
        else          { $firstLineInPair + ' ' + $_.TrimStart() } 
      }
    } 
  )
  ```

---

The **fastest and most concise solution** is to use a **[regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based approach**, which reads the entire file up front:

```bash
(Get-Content -Raw yourFile.txt) -replace '(.+)\r?\n(?: *)(.+\r?\n)', '$1 $2'
```

Note:

- The assumption is that all lines are paired, and that the last line has a trailing newline.
- The [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation matches two consecutive lines, and joins them together with a space, ignoring leading spaces on the second line. For a detailed explanation of the regex and the ability to interact with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/xRet3I/2).
- To save the output to a file, you can pipe directly to `Set-Content`:

  ```bash
  (Get-Content -Raw yourFile.txt) -replace '(.+)\r?\n(?: *)(.+\r?\n)', '$1 $2' |
    Set-Content yourOutputFile.txt
  ```

  - In this case, because the pipeline input to `Set-Content` is provided by an *expression* that doesn't involve for-every-input-line calls to [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) (as the `switch` solution requires), there is virtually no slowdown resulting from use of the pipeline (whose use is generally preferable for conceptual elegance and concision).

---

As for **what you tried**:

The `$splitLines`-based solution in your question is predicated on having assigned all lines of the input file to this self-chosen variable as an array, which your code does *not* do.

While you could fill variable `$splitLines` with an array of lines from your input file with `$splitLines = Get-Content yourFile.txt`, given that [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) reads text files *line by line* by default, the `switch`-based line-by-line solution is more efficient and *streams* its results (which - if saved to a file - keeps memory usage constant, which matters with large input sets (though rarely with *text* files)).

A performance tip when reading all lines at once into an array with `Get-Content`: use `-ReadCount 0`, which greatly speeds up the operation:

`$splitLines = Get-Content -ReadCount 0 yourFile.txt`