# How to rename multiple photos to the date

Tags: windows, powershell

I have multiple photos that taken on different dates.
I want to rename them all with a new name and by the date, like "New name"_20230601, "New Name"_20230602 etc.

I have used the code

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {"New Name" + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ($_.Extension)}
```

And it worked. It rename the photo as I want. However, when it comes to the multiple photos that I have taken on the same date, it only renamed just one photo and the rest stay unchanged.

What should I do if I want to rename all photo and those photo that I took on the same date also renamed with incrementing number, like "New name"_20230601(1),"New name"_20230601(2), "New name"_20230601(3) etc.

Comment: you have a scoping issue, `$script:index++` should solve your problem

Comment: You need a FOR loop.  Powershell you do not need to do everything in one instruction. Write the code like you would in c language.  Start with $children = Get-ChildItem; Foreach($child in Children){ add you code here}

Comment: sorry, I am very new to c language.  So, I should be adding **$script:index++**  in the code that I used? or I should not write all instruction in one code?

Comment: @RileyW: Sorry, the closure was premature. The language at hand is PowerShell, not C. In order to notify users of follow-up comments, you must @-mention them. `$script:index++` would help with _unconditional_ incrementing of a sequence number as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53393980/45375). However, in your case a robust solution requires deriving the next sequence number from how many files with the same name prefix already exist.

Comment: @jdweng: Stop treating PowerShell like a dialect of C#. Recommending against use of the core features of a language is absurd on its face. A [delay-bind script block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters), as used in the question, is an example of such a core feature: it enables concise, efficient solutions.

Comment: @mklement0 : Stop criticizing my style.  It is just as efficient as your solutions and my solutions are easier to understand and to debug.

Comment: @jdweng: I am criticizing your habitual recommendations not to 
use the features that make PowerShell PowerShell. I wish you'd stop doing so, but at the
very least you should make it crystal clear that you're opposing the fundamental design
of the language. I've addressed your arguments before, in the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75348106/45375

Comment: @mklement0 : Power Programming like you use is archaic.  It died 50 years ago.  Power Programming was needed when memory was expensive and programs had to be written so they could run with the limited resources of the computers of the 1960's.  Now it is more important to document and maintain programs.  People move from company to company and it is important to write code so new employees can maintain the code.

Comment: @jdweng: The only connection your response has to my comment is the word "power". As many times before, it is therefore an unhelpful distraction.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that any *preexisting* files have sequence numbers starting with base-name suffix `(1)` and are numbered *contiguously*, so that, with `<N>` preexisting files, `(<N>+1)` is the next suffix to be assigned; in the absence of preexisting files, it will rename based on this logic.

```bash
Get-ChildItem -File | 
  Rename-Item -NewName {
    $baseName = "New Name" + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    $existingCount = (
      Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $_.DirectoryName ($baseName + '*' + $_.Extension)) -File
    ).Count
    '{0}({1}){2}' -f $baseName, (1 + $existingCount), $_.Extension
  }
```